# Google Playstore - Ambiguity when moving from beta to production

Tags: android, google-play

I have just launched my app in private beta on Google Playstore. We are collecting feedback and working upon it. There are quite a few modifications, and we shall be updating the APK in private beta, and in a week post that shall move it to production for the public launch. I have 2 questions here:

1. Should the private beta users uninstall and reinstall the app once we push it to production? Or is there an option for them to update?
2. Do the installs count transfer over from the private beta to the production? E.g. If there are 150 users in private beta, would it show 100+ installs once we push it to production?

Also, is the answer to the above two questions different, if we are to do a public beta?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Should the private beta users uninstall and reinstall the app once we
>   push it to production? Or is there an option for them to update?

Yes, beta users need to uninstall and reinstall the app again from google play store.They won't get any update because beta is different release then the production one.

> Do the installs count transfer over from the private beta to the
>   production? E.g. If there are 150 users in private beta, would it show
>   100+ installs once we push it to production?

No, The beta installs count does not transfer from private beta to the production.

> Also, is the answer to the above two questions different, if we are to
>   do a public beta?

No,the answer remain same.For more detail check this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7003180)

Comment: Thanks a ton for the quick response Sunil. Tried searching a ton, but could not find that particular link. This surely helps.